# Allow users to Follow/Subscribe to chat rooms and receive notifications on activity?

Tags: feature-request, chat, notifications

Some of the less busy chatrooms may not receive messages for a few days. To save people checking in every couple of hours, it would be nice to be able to subscribe to particular rooms, and receive a notification when they see some activity.

This functionality would be similar to how 'Follow' now works on questions and answers.

Thoughts?

Comment: You can make RSS feeds out of chat searches and starred messages.

Comment: what is an RSS feed